# Uploading file to public directory with Laravel 5.5 and path seems strange

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am pretty well-versed in Laravel 5 and just need some clarification on how to do this correctly, because it does not feel right.

I have:

1. Symlinked a public/storage with /storage/app/public using Taylor's artisan command on my Homestead box, and it is working
2. I am making a request to an endpoint with the file, and actually able to store it correctly just fine.

My issue:

Because of the recommended symlink, if I use Taylor's `asset()` helper, it throws `public` in the URL and I have to chop the string up:

```
$game->cover_url = asset($path)
//returns http://homestead.app/public/covers/#######.jpg
```

And that is not correct, as it should be:

```
https://homestead.app/storage/covers/#######.jpg
```

Then I have to chop the path off:

```
$path = $request->file('coverImage')->store('public/covers');
$game->cover_url = substr($path, 7);
$game->save();
```

And then ultimately tack on `storage` in Vue. Would love to just get a URL to the right place. Any suggestions?

Feels like I have done something incorrectly.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue and it seems strange to me that I can't find anyone else talking about it.

Comment: Sorry to bug you about this ancient topic,  I was actually just able to figure it out. I just used Storage::url() instead of asset().

Comment: @bb89 That's interesting -- maybe it's hooked up so that if you have used the Symlink, it will still go to the correct place in the public directory...